# Alternative definition of Legendre polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, definition, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I'm studying Panofsky and Phillips' *Classical Electricity and Magnetism*. In writing the potential of a linear $2^n$-pole lying along the $x$-axis, they make use of the following definition for the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).
$$
\frac{P_n(\cos\theta)}{r^{n+1}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} \left(\frac{1}{r}\right).
$$

Here, $r:=|\mathbf{r - r_0}|$ and I guess that $\theta$ is the angle that $(\mathbf{r-r_0})$ makes with the $x$-axis (the authors don't mention abot $\theta$). Further I'm not even sure if the RHS is evaluated at $\mathbf r = 0$.

I'm only barely familiar with the Legendre functions and I am not able to show that the above matches with the standard definitions of the Legendre functions. I'll be happy if you can help me see the equivalence with the Rodrigue's formula.

Comment: Can you give us the exact equation in the book and perhaps all other details. What is x?

Comment: @PraharMitra $x$ is the first coordinate, corresponding to the $x$-axis. Writing more explicitly, $r=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2}$.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I agree. Can you move it? Or should I ask separately there?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the standard generating-function formula
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2-2x\cos\theta}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n P_n(\cos\theta), \quad |x|<1
$$
in disguise as the formula for its  Taylor series coefficients
$$
P_n(\cos \theta) =\left. \frac 1 {n!} \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2-2x\cos\theta}}\right|_{x=0}
$$

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m not able to scratch any deeper.